# "secret option is required for sessions"

Tags: session, socket.io, chat, express-session

I am using socket.io to build a real time chat system but whenever i configure express-session with an env var as the secret socket.io will throw the `secret option is required for sessions` when connecting from the client. This does not happen if the secret option is directly set with a plain text string.

Before the first script below is used the env vars are correctly imported with dotenv, in fact the there is no error related to undefined env vars.

*Session*

```
import session from "express-session";
import generateRandomString from "../functions/generate-random-string";

export default session({
    name: "session_token",
    genid: () => {
        return generateRandomString(300)
    },
    secret: <string> process.env.COOKIES_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        //domain: <string> process.env.HOST,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        sameSite: "lax",
        secure: true,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
})
```

*index.ts*

```
mongo().then(() => {
    const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server online on PORT ${PORT}`);
    });
    
    initSocketServer(server);
});
```

*initSocketServer*

```
import { Server as ioServer } from "socket.io";
import session from "../middlewares/session";
import { Server } from "http";

const wrap = (middleware: any) => (socket: any, next: any) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);

const io: ioServer = new ioServer();

io.use(wrap(session));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id + " connected");
})

export default async (server: Server) => io.listen(server);
```

Socket.IO client version: `4.5.4`

*Client*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-/KNQL8Nu5gCHLqwqfQjA689Hhoqgi2S84SNUxC3roTe4EhJ9AfLkp8QiQcU8AMzI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"></script>
    <script>eruda.init();</script>
    <script>
        const host = "https://example.com"; // This HTML file is served on the same domain as the server

        async function fetchToken() {
            return await fetch(host + "/v1/tokens/generate", {
                method: "POST"
            }).then(async (data) => {
                data = await data.json();

                return data.token;
            })
        }

        ;(async () => {
            const socket = io({
                auth: {
                    "x-csrf-token": await fetchToken()
                }
            });

            socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            })

            socket.connect();
        })();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you print `process.env.COOKIES_SECRET` to debug it?

Comment: @LinDu i already did and it was not undefined. Also `dotenv.config()` was called at the top of the entry script so all the env vars were correctly imported.